# How to apply linear transform on a 3D feature vector in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Imagine there is a tensor with the following dimensions `(32, 20, 3)` where **batch_size** = 32, **num_steps** = 20 and **features** = 3. The features are taken from a .csv file that has the following format:

```
feat1, feat2, feat3
200, 100, 0
5.5, 200, 0.5
23.2, 1, 9.3
```

Each row is transformed into 3-dim vector (numpy array): `[200, 100, 0]`, `[5.5, 200, 0.5]`, `[23.2, 1, 9.3]`.

We want to use these features in a recurrent neural network but directly feeding them into rnn won't do, we'd like to process these feature vectors first by applying linear transformation to each 3-dim vector inside the batch sample and reshape the input tensor into `(32, 20, 100)`.

This is easily done in Torch for example via: `nn.MapTable():add(nn.Linear(3, 100))` which is applied on the input batch tensor of size `20 x 32 x 3` (num_steps and batch_size are switched in Torch). We split it into 20 arrays each `32x3` in size

```
  1 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x3
  2 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x3
  3 : DoubleTensor - size: 32x3
  ...
```

and use `nn.Linear(3, 100)` to transform them into `32x100` vectors. We then pack them up back into `20 x 32 x 100` tensor. How can we implement the same operation in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could reshape into [batchsize*num_steps, features] use a Tensorflow linear layer with 100 outputs and then reshape back would that work?

```
reshaped_tensor = tf.reshape(your_input, [batchsize*num_steps, features])
linear_out = tf.layers.dense(inputs=reshaped_tensor, units=100)
reshaped_back = tf.reshape(linear_out, [batchsize, num_steps, features]
```